# PHP Select From Postgres Unexpected Character

Tags: php, postgresql, select, pgadmin, php-pgsql

I have an application written in PHP, I'm connecting to a PGSQL database and selecting some data. This works as expected until I use the string concatenation operator (||) in the query.

I connected tothe PGSQL db via PGadmin and generated the query, so I know it definitely works. I then copied the code and pasted it into my `$query` variable.

My code is below;

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=xxx dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$query = ' 
SELECT
f.date_gmt::date as "Date Assessed"
n.last_name || ', '' || n.first_name AS "Full Name" // line 12
FROM
fines as f
JOIN
record_metadata as r
ON
r.id = f.record_metadata_id
JOIN
fullname as n
ON
n.id = f.record_metadata_id
';

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

pg_free_result($result);
pg_close($dbconn);
```

The error produced is;

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in
>   /...index.php on line 12

Removing line 12 from the code resolves the issue. But, I need this data so what do I need to change in order to achieve what I want?

Presumably I can't simply copy the working query from the PGSQL db and paste it into my PHP code?

Comment: This is wrong:  || ', '' ||  you have closed the string followed by a coma, if you want that in the query string escape the '.

Comment: Or use heredoc format

Comment: Could you give an example please @TimMorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not escape quote symbols `'`.
You have 2 options.

1st escape them with back slashes:

```
n.last_name || \', \'\' || n.first_name AS "Full Name"
```

2nd (suggested) Just use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) notation:

```
$query = <<<QUERY
SELECT
f.date_gmt::date as "Date Assessed"
n.last_name || ', '' || n.first_name AS "Full Name"
FROM
fines as f
JOIN
record_metadata as r
ON
r.id = f.record_metadata_id
JOIN
fullname as n
ON
n.id = f.record_metadata_id
QUERY;
```

Example [here](https://ideone.com/vrI2xm).

`||` is concatenation operator for Postgres. I think you have typo there and this line

```
n.last_name || ', '' || n.first_name AS "Full Name"
```

has a typo, should be

```
n.last_name || '', '' || n.first_name AS "Full Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes in a string delimited by single quotes:

```
'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = '123''
```

You need to escape them. IIRC, Postgres uses double singles to do this:

```
'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ''123'''
```

Or perhaps backslashes:

```
'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = \'123\''
```